# Using a webhook from Google Cloud Functions with Dialogflow CX

Tags: google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-cx

I managed to successfully implement a webhook with Dialogflow CX in a repl environment and flask, but not sure how to move the webhook onto Google Cloud Functions. I've scoured the web for a tutorials, but most are in Dialogflow ES. Any help is appreciated!

This is my current code on repl:

```
from flask import Flask, request
app = Flask(__name__)

def create_json_response(response_text, updated_params):
  jsonResponse = {
    "fulfillment_response":
      {
        "messages": [
          {
            "text": {
              "text": [
                str(response_text)
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }, 
    "sessionInfo": {
    "parameters": updated_params
            }
  }
  return jsonResponse
  
@app.route('/webhook', methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
  req = request.get_json(silent=True, force=True)
  fulfillmentInfo = req.get('fulfillmentInfo')
  
  if fulfillmentInfo['tag'] == 'add':
    updated_params = {}
    total = 0
    num1 = int(req.get('sessionInfo').get('parameters').get('number'))
    num2 = int(req.get('sessionInfo').get('parameters').get('number1'))
    total = str(num1 + num2)
    updated_params['previous1'] = num1
    updated_params['previous2'] = num2
    updated_params['number'] = None
    updated_params['number1'] = None
    jsonResponse = create_json_response(total, updated_params)
    return jsonResponse


  elif fulfillmentInfo['tag'] == 'multiply':
    updated_params = {}
    total = 0
    num1 = int(req.get('sessionInfo').get('parameters').get('number'))
    num2 = int(req.get('sessionInfo').get('parameters').get('number1'))
    total = str(num1 * num2)
    updated_params['previous1'] = num1
    updated_params['previous2'] = num2
    updated_params['number'] = None
    updated_params['number1'] = None
    jsonResponse = create_json_response(total, updated_params)
    return jsonResponse
  

  

@app.route('/') # this is the home page route
def hello_world(): # this is the home page function that generates the page code
    return "Hello Beautiful World!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080) # This line is required to run Flask on repl.it
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question! I just needed to pass request as a parameter in my webhook function. Derp!